# What to do if subtracting in binary overflows

Tags: binary

I am trying to do this equation -122 -(7) and in the result i'm getting = 01111111

I used 2's complement for -122 and got = 10000110. And I used 2's complement for 7 so I can make addition and got = 11111001. And when I am adding both I am getting = 01111111 with carry 1. I don't think this is correct answer for -129

Comment: So what is the eight-bit representation of -129?

Comment: I am not sure, but is that correct answer?
Normally I would say its 127

Answer (score 0):

#### Ignore the Overflow Bit

Two's complement with a bit-width of 8 has a range of [-128, 127].

This binary math shows what (-122) + (-7) is equal to.

```
  122 =>    01111010
  7   =>    00000111

  -122 =>   10000110
  -7   =>   11111001
+         +
------    ----------
  127     1 01111111

01111111 => 127
```

In this example, we see that there is an overflow bit designating -256. -256 is outside of the 8-bit range of [-128, 127]. Most implementations will drop this overflow bit, and so the result would be **127**.

#### Further Reading

There are other stackoverflow answers that delve into two's complement overflow in greater detail if you're curious.

- [How is overflow detected in two's complement?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32960835/1596750)
- [Do we ignore overflow in Two's Complement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27868785/1596750)